# are there log files for windows mobile phone 7 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation

I'm doing some development for windows mobile phone 7.  I have the emulator installed and can deploy and debug the application.  However, I'm getting random application crashes that I'm trying to debug.  When I've worked with other emulators, there are log files that give log details from system libraries and other framework components that are being used.

Are there any such logs with mobile emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it the emulator that is crashing? Or the application?

If its the application, then you should be able to use the VS2010 debugger with "break on exceptions" turned on and with intellitrace options.

If its the emulator, then sorry - but I don't know of any log files available.